# get passwords from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to access save passwords in chrome extension? I was looking through API but did not find it.. I want to export all passwords into different storage and using extension seems like logical way to do it, but I cannot find HOW to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be a very serious security issue if you could.

Comment: There must be a way (probably not via the API) though, since LastPass is able to import from saved chrome passwords

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the only way to do that is via NPAPI, by accessing the file system where the password database (SQLite) is stored.

Comment: I dont think it would be easy to crack SQLite DB and get all sensitive data, but i would love to see any such hacking code :)

Comment: yeah, I know where they are stored, but I hoped I would not have to break password encryption.. I hope somebody did it before me. While chromium is opensource, my c is not that good to just find the encryption algorithm in it's code :/

Comment: ok, so linux does not encrypt login informations.. little scary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question, it does not seem possible to access that information via extension API, but on linux (linux does not encrypt login information, windows does) all you need is to access `"~/.config/chromium/Default/Login Data"` and extract data from logins table. It's sqlite3 db.

So it could be done with NPAPI.

Comment: According to http://security.stackexchange.com/a/22597/132108 Linux does hash login information.  How would it be acceptable for an OS to leave login credentials in plain text?

Comment: @AllTradesJack from the link: "The passwords aren't encrypted, they're hashed. It is mathematically impossible to derive the original password from the hash." - well... that sounds like pretty useless password manager.. if it cannot recover original password, how does it fill the password field on websites?