# Programatically import passwords from Chrome Password Manager onto Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm working on my first chrome extension. Its a password manager app with some additional functionalities over the chrome default password manager.

Now I have a request from client to fetch all the passwords from the chrome password manager and store it in the chrome extension.

I have browsed through many stackoverflow posts and other posts online, but none of them answer achieving this in a chrome extension. I know this is definitely achievable as there are third party apps like LastPass, ChromePass which have implemented this.

Could somebody please give me some pointers on how to go about with this? I know Chrome stores the password data in DB named 'Login Data' and the password will be stored encrypted which is OS dependent.

Comment: Do you have evidence any of those tools actually work with the current version of Chrome?

Comment: Yes, they do. I have tried LastPass with the latest Chrome browser.

Comment: And it imported browser-stored passwords? WIth or without binary helper app? I mean, they don't use any special permissions that would allow them to do so.

Comment: @Xan Im not sure about the implementation, but they are able to import all the passwords and use it in their chrome plugin.

Comment: The [LastPass doc](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/importing-from-other-password-managers/) for importing passwords only mentions Chrome in relation to wifipasswords while using their native app.

Comment: @abraham Sorry, I didn't get your point. The doc mentions the instructions to import from passwords. Out of that I'm looking for a way to import password from the Chrome password manager.

Comment: @abraham I have used the LastPass chrome extension and I did not had to  install any native app. Please let me know if that is one of the way. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the LastPass extension had an NPAPI plugin at least at some point (which are being deprecated); however, it is unlikely that there is any legitimate (or easy) method to extract passwords from the password manager. If there were, it would be an attractive target for malware.

Comment: @gengkev Yes, I understand. From this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426841/get-passwords-from-chrome I see there is no easy way of implementing this. Native client seems to be an alternative for NPAPI plugin. Might that work?

Comment: @Adithya As far as I can tell, NaCl is only a replacement in that you can run native code; however, it runs in a sandbox and can't access the user's filesystem. Probably the only viable solution is to ask users to download a separate executable.

Comment: @gengkev Separate exe? How will the chrome plugin have access to that?

Comment: @gengkev A "separate exe" is exactly what is called "Native Host", not Native Client, but that's probably what was meant.

Comment: @Adithya Chrome has a [native messaging API](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/10/connecting-chrome-apps-and-extensions.html) that is designed for this use. good luck with your extension!

Answer (score 4):

I maintain an informed guess that this is impossible (and the documentation you link to does NOT mention it), unless you employ an external module (native host).

There are no specific APIs that allow extensions to access password database, neither public nor, to my knowledge, private (LastPass extension has no private APIs in the manifest). Which is good from the security perspective.

As for the native host approach - even then you'll have to somehow tap into Chrome's encrypted password file. Its format changed over time and I doubt there are currently tools that can break it. It may be possible to replicate the functionality Chrome has to access the file with the user's master password, but it will be hard.

---

In fact, Chrome's own database would fall under the ["Passive Imports" part](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/importing-from-other-password-managers/#Passive+Imports) of the documentation. I suspect LastPass just picks up passwords as they are inserted by Chrome, but only while you visit sites that are protected with said passwords.

Comment: I have used LastPass and it has a separate option to import from the password managers. As soon as I chose the Chrome default password manager options, all the password entries got imported and were available for use.

Comment: I believe that the LastPass importer mentioned is a Windows app, not an extension.  It can read the passwords from the filesystem.  They are not plain text or anything, but can easily be decrypted by a process running under the user's profile.